# Method returns right value outside of function, inside function returns NULL

Tags: php, function

Can someone help me understand this? It seams like I have done this a 100 times already, but for some reason I can't get it to work now.

I have a MySQL class where I do my SQL stuff.

I have a file called `ajax.php` which I do some AJAX requests to. In this file I have:

```
$mysql = new Mysql($server, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbselect);
$show =$mysql->count('temp_vipalm', "21");   
var_dump($show);
```

This returns the correct value as I expected. Now I want to use this in a function, so I can make it a little more dynamic, so in the same ajax.php file I create this function:

```
function menu($barid,$type)
{
    //echo $barid; // returns correct value
    //echo $bartype; //returns correct value

$mysql = new Mysql($server, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbselect);
   //usually $barid and $type goes in here, but I hardcoded the values for testing.
$show =$mysql->count('temp_vipalm', "21");   
var_dump($show);
}
```

Now when running `menu('21', 'temp_vipalm');` it returns `NULL`.

No matter what I do, it keeps returning `NULL` when inside the function - can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$server`, `$dbuser`, `$dbpass`, and `$dbselect` variables are global. Within the function scope, you'll have to declare that those variables are coming from the global scope. Try this:

```
function menu($barid, $type) {
{
    global $server, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbselect;
    $mysql = new Mysql($server, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbselect);
    // ...
}
```

Note: It would be a better idea to make these constants instead of variables. It's usually best to avoid variables in the global scope. If you accidentally overwrite one of those values somewhere else in your code, this function will use the wrong values.

Comment: Will accept your answer in 9 minutes - again thanks a lot! I get these values from a config file, so I forgot about this completely. Cheers! :)

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped. Please notice my note at the end...it would probably be a good idea to make them constants instead of variables, especially when they're in the global scope.

Comment: would setting them global in the config file, be better?

Comment: By setting them in your config file, outside of any class or function, they *are* global. Using the `global` keyword in your function is telling the function that these variables are declared in the global scope. Making them constants inside the config file would be better. See [`define()`](http://us1.php.net/define) for how to declare a constant. Then you won't need to use `global`.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I will check that out. Really been banging my head against the wall the last few hours.. huge help!

Answer (score 1):

The variables `$server, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbselect` are not declared in the scope of the function, you should declare them as `global` assuming they're defined in the global env.

Answer (score 1):

There's two things to be aware of:

1. global variables must be declared global inside a function
2. the variable must already have been initialised

so this works fine:

```
<?php
$fred=42;

function printFred(){
  global $fred;   // declare it global
  echo "fred is: ". $fred . "\n";
}

printFred();
?>
```

whereas this does not do what you might expect:

```
<?php

echo "Starting program...\n";
printStuff();
echo "the end";
exit();


$jim="Hello I'm jim";

function printStuff(){
  global $jim;
  echo $jim . "\n";
}
?>
```

because, in this case, the statement "$jim="Hello I'm jim";" is never executed.

Yours,
  TonyWilk